# Run same script / test cases with different 10 different usernames, using selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

Please instead of giving a negative to the question help me to get it right.
This is the code which I use to login as one user using the username,

```
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);         
        driver.FindElement(By.ID("login")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.ID("user")).SendKeys(Username1);
        driver.FindElement(By.ID("pass")).SendKeys(password);
        driver.FindElement(By.ID("access")).Click();
```

How would I use different usernames to run the same code one after the other

```
  readonly static string Username1 = "User1"
  readonly static string Username2 = "User2"
  readonly static string Username3 = "User3"
  reasonly static string password =  "passqwert"
```

once I login in then the rest of the test cases are executed. The test cases don't change for any user just need to log in with different usernames.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't really a tutorial site, which is kind of what you're asking for. There are dozens of ways to handle variables, because that's really all this is, which makes your question extremely broad.

You could narrow the scope a bit by providing your script and telling us what you tried, as well as why it didn't work. 

That might still leave it too broad for this site, but you'd be closer. Outside of that,  you should probably look up C# tutorials to get a grasp of the basics.

Comment: Thanks, @TylerMacMillan I will edit the question and add code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to leverage the unit test framework you are using. So for example if you're using MsTest you could use the DataRow attribute like so...

```
  readonly static string password = "passqwert";   

  [DataTestMethod]
  [DataRow("User1")]
  [DataRow("User2")]
  [DataRow("User3")]
  public void TheTest(string username)
  {
        ...
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);         
        driver.FindElement(By.ID("login")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.ID("user")).SendKeys(username);
        driver.FindElement(By.ID("pass")).SendKeys(password);
        driver.FindElement(By.ID("access")).Click();
  }
```

Similar things can be achieved if using other test frameworks such as NUnit or xUnit.

Comment: Thanks for the response that gives me a few ideas to try out thanks :)